# Celery with base 10 Redis Password

Tags: redis, celery

I would like to start celery worker with defined redis password. I have password with base 10 password for my redis password. When I start my celery worker, it showed error like this:

```
[2017-09-08 08:31:33,747: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: 

ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A=@redisserversomewhere:6380/14'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 115, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 143, in on_start
    self.emit_banner()
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 158, in emit_banner
    ' \n', self.startup_info(artlines=not use_image))),
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 221, in startup_info
    results=self.app.backend.as_uri(),
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1183, in backend
    return self._get_backend()
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 902, in _get_backend
    return backend(app=self, url=url)
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.connparams = self._params_from_url(url, self.connparams)
  File "/home/apppython/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 181, in _params_from_url
    connparams['db'] = int(db)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A=@redisserversomewhere:6380/14'
```

I got a password for redis like this:

redis://dsa86321hsd792194e8r1MiFyxz+9r/A=@redisserversomewhere:6380/14

How should I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You happen to have solved this since last year?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I did this app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://:'+str(dataConfig['redis']['password'])+'@'+str(dataConfig['redis']['url'])+':'+str(dataConfig['redis']['port'])+'/'+str(dataConfig['redis']['db'])